# Citrus Payment Gateway Integration in Android Mobile App

Tags: android, citrus-pay, citrus-android-sdk

All !!!

I am integration Citrus Payment gateway in my app. I am having http://developers.citruspay.com which contains all the necessary steps.

My question is regarding prerequisites for this. the site says

> 1. Secret Key
> 2. Access Key
> 3. SignIn Key
> 4. SignIn Secret
> 5. SignUp Key
> 6. SignUp Secret
> 7. Bill Generator Hosted on your server.
> 8. Redirect URL page hosted on your server. (After the transaction is complete, Citrus posts a response to this URL.)
> 9. Redirect URL-LoadCash page hosted on your server (To handle LoadMoney response, refer this link)?

I need to ask what is signin/signup key and signin/signup secret?

I have only app secrets. Can anyone help me out for thsi problem?

Comment: From Citrus I have User Name , Password, Access Key,
Checkout Page URL,
Custom Checkout Page URL,
Secret Key  only.

Answer (score 0):

You can get signin/signup key and signin/signup secret. As there documentations says:

```
Client side keys: For below mentioned keys , kindly download mobile SDK keystore.json 
file from merchant panel.
SignIn Key (consumerClientId)
SignIn Secret (consumerClientSecret)
SignUp Key (merchantClientId)
SignUp Secret (merchantClientSecret)
```

Check out the link for more: https://developers.citruspay.com/doc/integrations/

Comment: JSON that I have obtained has all the values null, save vanity. What steps am I missing? `{"access_key":hkhkhk","merchantClientId":"null","merchantClientSecret":"null","consumerClientId":"null","consumerClientSecret":"null","vanity":"hjhkjhk"}`